# Nav table of content expand and collapse Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with make "table of content" expand and collapse with a button in Bootstrap 4.

Here is my code:
https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/RwwwyKB

Snippet:

```
<div class="main-wrapper col-12">
    <div class="post-wrapper">
        <div class="post-body d-flex">
            <div class="post-content">
                <p>...</p>
            </div>

            <div class="post-toc">
                <!-- this table of content i use Boostrap-TOC to auto generate: https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc-->         
                <nav class="sticky-top" id="toc"></nav>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can you guys please help me to put "table of contens" inside a colapse button and when clicked it we have animation like the images below.

[image]

[image]

Thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To animate the side menu you have to make a `transformation` and slide the menu using `translateX(100%);`. You can then add a `transition: all 300ms;` to have a sliding effect.

You will also need to change the side menu width as you are sliding, so the content fills the space of the side menu.

I think I achieved the effect you wanted, Example below:
https://codepen.io/diogoperes/pen/NWWWMYW

Comment: That's it. so great!!! Thank you so much sir. 
By the way, can you please make the button change to another button after click. and i wonder that can that button not fixed anymore if i scroll down over the article.

Comment: Your welcome, glad it helped. If this question solved your problem please mark with a checkmark so others know it's solved. I will try to make the button change.

Comment: Thank you sir. i marked my post as solved. I see that your perfect button stay fixed on the top of article. Can you please make it not fixed anymore if i scroll down over the aritcle. It mean that if i scroll down to footer, i don't see button any more beause i am not reading the article. I really hope to hear from you soon, sir. 
Again, thank you so much sir.

Comment: oh i got it. it's position: sticky;.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you check now? to see if that's what you want.

Comment: can you please make it instead of pushing the content, making the content width smaller, it will push the "<div> contain content" from center to the left. Thanks again sir.

Comment: Done! Just removed the d-flex width which is the parents width.

Comment: You are so great, sir. i don't know how to say but you saved my day. I spent all day working on it but it didn't work. Thank you so much, sir. It's perfect. I wish i have enough reputation to upvote for you. Once again, thank you so much sir.

Comment: @Thuat Nguyen You're welcome, glad I was able to help. You can upvote once you have reputation :) Happy coding!

Comment: Hi sir, i came back a little early. And i really don't want to bother you because you helped me a lot but I encountered a problem and i really don't know what to do. 

I tried to make content is centered (not both content and button are centered), and the button is closer to the right margin. And when table of content is expanded, the content is moved closer to the left, but the content's width not change.

Comment: Like content's width is 75% and is in the centered, the button is closer to the right (not centered with content). When table of content is expanded, it has width: 20%. And content now is moved closer to the left, layout has two column side by side. 

Thank you so much sir, and i am so sory because i bother you again.

Comment: It's better to create a new question explaining what you want. I'm not understanding clearly and this thread it's getting really big.

Comment: Thank you sir. I created a new one here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260777/make-a-toggle-absolute-button-become-sticky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260777/make-a-toggle-absolute-button-become-sticky). Could you please help me once more times, sir.

Answer (score 0):

I added some animation with jQuery, as well as added the button and some Bootstrap classes, to bring your main content at the center.

Here's the jQuery method:

```
$(function() {
  $("#toc-button").click( function() {
    $(".post-toc").stop(true).animate({width:'toggle'}, 400);
  });
});
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/evelyng/pen/XWWWqYg

Comment: Finally. Thank you so much, sir. By the way, can you please make that button change to another button after expand. one button to expand, other to close. and can that button fixed in top of article but after i scroll down over aritcle to the footer it will not be fixed any more.

Thank you so much sir.