# Make a toggle absolute button become sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having problem making a sticky button in the code below.

https://codepen.io/nht910/pen/KKKKerQ

Snippet:

```
<div class="post-body d-flex justify-content-center">
    <!-- content -->
    <div class="post-content">
        <p>
            ...
        </p>    
    </div>

    <!-- button toggle -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="toc-button">
        button
    </button>

    <!-- table of contents -->
    <div class="post-toc">
        <nav class="sticky-top" id="toc"></nav>
    </div>

</div>
```

The button in this code has property "position: absolute;". I tried to change this property to "position: sticky" but it breaks the layout, it makes content that is not centered anymore.

And by default, on page load, the table of contents is expanded already.

Can you guys please help me to make that button become sticky inside the parent div ".post-body" like the table of contents and stay above the table of contents? And please help me to make the table of contents is closed on page load, too.

Thank you guys so much.

Comment: Have you tried to apply `position: relative` to the parent?

Comment: I add "position: relative" to ".post-body" but still not working, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the button after the table of contents and `position: sticky`.

Example:
https://codepen.io/diogoperes/pen/KKKKbQd

Comment: Thank you, sir. But i need it to be sticky (fixed) just inside the parent div, sir.

Comment: Then try sticky or static property for position

Comment: @diogoperes but the content is not centered anymore, sir.

Comment: Use top bottom right and left properties to be used with position: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility of autoscroll if there are a lot of headings and the ToC menu becomes too long?
You can test what I mean by making the preview window of height from the codepen.io examples very low. So that only 1-2 headlines are displayed in the ToC menu. The menu selection disappears and you don't know where you are in the content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it looks more like a comment to me. Consider commenting directly under the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I cannot comment because of "You must have 50 reputation to comment".

Comment: Oh, okay, that's indeed unfortunate.